# Pass GenericList to Observable Collection

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have Generic List

```
GetAllSponsor sponsorlist = new GetAllSponsor();
sponsorlist.getallsponsor();
string spnsrlst = sponsorlist.ToFormattedJsonString();

Sponsors sponsorObjectData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Sponsors>(spnsrlst);
```

Here is Sponsors Class definition looks like:

```
public class Sponsors
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string company_name { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public string sponsor_level { get; set; }
            public string picture { get; set; }
            public string location { get; set; }
            public string website_url { get; set; }
            public string sm_twitter { get; set; }
            public string sm_facebook { get; set; }
            public string sm_linkedin { get; set; }
            public string sm_pinterest { get; set; }
            public string contact_number { get; set; }
            public string attachments { get; set; }
            public string date_time { get; set; }


        }
```

I need to pass it to `Observable Collection`.

How I can do this?

Comment: I would return a list from GetAllSponsor().  Then just loop through the list, adding each to the ObservableCollection.  The way you are doing it, I assume that you are getting some sort of array in the deserialized object - you could loop through that, but it seems inefficient to create json and immediately deserialize it.

Comment: How I can return list from `GetAllSponsor`? @ElementalPete

Comment: It depends what GetAllSponsor is doing... Are you getting info from a database? From a web service?  From the hard drive?

Comment: Look, my problem in what.

I havу Adapter for RecyclerView 
[Adapter link](https://github.com/suhomlineugene/TieiT/blob/master/MvvmCross/Adapters/SponsorAdapter.cs)


As I understood, I need to pass Observable Collection to this adapter. @ElementalPete

Comment: Nope. I get `json` from api. You can see it here [JSONDownloader](https://github.com/suhomlineugene/TieiT/blob/master/MvvmCross/DownloadClasses/GetAllSponsor.cs) @ElementalPete

Comment: OK, so you don't have control over the code in GetAllSponsor, so you can't control what it returns.  Your class "Sponsors" can only hold one object, so if there is more than one sponsor (as GetAllSponsors implies) then you probably have a problem with the way your class is defined.  This class should probably be called "Sponsor", and what are actually getting back is probably an array of those...  If we can see some raw json, I could tell you for sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125138/discussion-between-eugene-and-elemental-pete).

Answer (score 1):

```
List<SomeType> list = new List<SomeType>();

// add items to list 

ObservableCollection<SomeType> collection = new ObservableCollection<SomeType>(list);
```

Comment: This works as long as you only do it once when you initialize the class that has the ObservableCollection.  Assuming that the ObservableCollection is being used for binding so that updates are visible to a view, if you run this after binding to collection, it will not communicate those updates because it is a new ObservableCollection (not the one that he is binding to)

Comment: you should have included your use case in your question.  But AFAIK the only way to do it with an existing collection is to iterate through the list and add each item manually

Answer (score 0):

To summarize our chat, I would move the download code out of that class.  The class should be called Sponsor (since it represents a single sponsor), and it should just hold public properties for the data fields that you are receiving (ID, company_name, description, etc.)  The JSON that you are getting is actually an array of Sponsors, so you need to deserialize it to a `List<Sponsor>` or something appropriate.  Then, loop through your list, and add each sponsor to the ObservableCollection like this:

```
foreach (Sponsor s in mySponsors) 
{
   myCollection.Add(s);
}
```